# What does it mean "Not in scope: ‘trace" and how can i resolve this?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run a program but i get always this in the terminal fib3.hs:3:12: Not in scope: ‘trace’ and i don't know what does it mean or how can i resolve this. I'm a ver beginner and haskell...
my code

```
-- fib3.hs
fib   :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib d n |  trace (shift d ++ "Call: fib " ++ show n)
                     False = 0
fib _ 0 = 0
fib _ 1 = 1
fib d n = fib (d+1) (n-1)
          + fib (d+1) (n-2)

shift :: Integer -> String
shift 0 = ""
shift n =  "   " ++ shift (n-1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that Haskell cannot find the function `trace` - the problem is, that it's not in the prelude but in the [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) module so you have to import this.

The easiest way to do this would be to add

```
import Debug.Trace
```

below your `module` definition (if you have one - if not just at the top of the file but blow `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` pragmas (if there are any)

This will import *everything* from `Debug.Trace` which I personally don't like (it's hard to find out where a function is defined this way) - that's why I usually prefer to import only the needed functions and definitions (so I can tell where they are coming from) like this:

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)
```

So a solution to your problem could look like this:

```
module MyFibModule where

import Debug.Trace (trace)

-- fib3.hs
fib   :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib d n |  trace (shift d ++ "Call: fib " ++ show n)
                     False = 0
fib _ 0 = 0
fib _ 1 = 1
fib d n = fib (d+1) (n-1)
          + fib (d+1) (n-2)

shift :: Integer -> String
shift 0 = ""
shift n =  "   " ++ shift (n-1)

...
```

**voila**:

```
λ> fib 1 4
   Call: fib 4
      Call: fib 2
         Call: fib 0
         Call: fib 1
      Call: fib 3
         Call: fib 1
         Call: fib 2
            Call: fib 0
            Call: fib 1
3
```

---

The rest is **off topic** but it might be interesting to you:

#### slight rewrite

I would rewrite this into:

```
fib   :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib d 0 = traceIt d 0 $ 0
fib d 1 = traceIt d 1 $ 1
fib d n = traceIt d n $ fib (d+1) (n-1) + fib (d+1) (n-2)

traceIt :: Integer -> Integer -> a -> a
traceIt d n = trace (shift d ++ "Call: fib " ++ show n)

shift :: Integer -> String
shift 0 = ""
shift n =  "   " ++ shift (n-1)
```

the **guard**-*trick* there seems to be too much *magic* IMO (I obviously totally missed the point at first :( ... so you decide: am I to stupid or is the code to arcane to read?)

### don't want to repeat it so much

In case you don't like that you have to prepend the `traceIt d n` everywhere (which is nasty yes) you can make *fix* the recursion with the `trace`:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib = fib' 0

fib' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib' d n = traceIt d n $ fibF (fib' (d+1)) n

fibF :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
fibF _ 0 = 0
fibF _ 1 = 1
fibF f n = f (n-1) + f (n-2)

traceIt :: Integer -> Integer -> a -> a
traceIt d n = trace (shift d ++ "Call: fib " ++ show n)
```

#### example

```
λ> fib 4
Call: fib 4
   Call: fib 2
      Call: fib 0
      Call: fib 1
   Call: fib 3
      Call: fib 1
      Call: fib 2
         Call: fib 0
         Call: fib 1
3
```

Comment: The output indentation looks fine to me: every recursive call is more indented.